# How to make dataframe from web scraped variables?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape a real estate website. The problem is that I can't insert my scraped variables into one `dataframe`.

Here is my code:

```
html_text1=requests.get('https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/search?c=1&ob=mr&page=1').content
soup1=BeautifulSoup(html_text1,'lxml')

listings=soup1.find_all('a',class_='card card--clickable')
for listing in listings:
 price=listing.find('p', class_='card__price').text.split()[0]
 price=price.split()[0]
 title=listing.find('h2', class_='card__title card__title-link').text
 property_type=listing.find('p',class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--property-type').text
 bedrooms=listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bedrooms').text
 bathrooms=listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bathrooms').text
 location=listing.find('p', class_='card__location').text

 dataset=pd.DataFrame({property_type, price, title, bedrooms, bathrooms, location})
 print(dataset)
```

My output looks like this:
[image]

However, I want it to look like a `DataFrame`:

Apartment | 162500   | ...

Townhouse | 162500   | ...

Villa     | 7500000  | ...

Villa     | 15000000 | ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you are trying to create a `dataframe` from within the `for` loop. What you should be doing is creating lists to store these values separately in `lists` and then creating a `df` from these `lists`.

Here's what the code will look like:

```
price_lst = []
title_lst = []
propertyType_lst = []
bedrooms_lst = []
bathrooms_lst = []
location_lst = []


listings = soup1.find_all('a',class_='card card--clickable')
for listing in listings:
    price = listing.find('p', class_='card__price').text.split()[0]
    price = price.split()[0]
    price_lst.append(price)

    title = listing.find('h2', class_='card__title card__title-link').text
    title_lst.append(title)

    property_type = listing.find('p',class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--property-type').text
    propertyType_lst.append(property_type)
    
    bedrooms = listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bedrooms').text
    bedrooms_lst.append(bedrooms)

    bathrooms = listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bathrooms').text
    bathrooms_lst.append(bathrooms)

    location = listing.find('p', class_='card__location').text
    location_lst.append(location)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(propertyType_lst, price_lst, title_lst, bedrooms_lst, bathrooms_lst, location_lst)), 
                                columns = ['Property Type', 'Price', 'Title', 'Bedrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'Location'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend to work with a bit more structur - Use `dicts` or list of dicts to store the data of your iteration and create a data frame in the end:

```
data = []

for listing in listings:
    price=listing.find('p', class_='card__price').text.split()[0].split()[0]
    title=listing.find('h2').text
    property_type=listing.find('p',class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--property-type').text
    bedrooms=listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bedrooms').text
    bathrooms=listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bathrooms').text
    location=listing.find('p', class_='card__location').text
    
    data.append({
        'price':price,
        'title':title,
        'property_type':property_type,
        'bedrooms':bedrooms,
        'bathrooms':bathrooms,
        'location':location
    })
```

**Note:** *Also check the your selections to avoid `AttributeErrors`*

```
title=t.text if (t:=listing.find('h2')) else None
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

html_text1=requests.get('https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/search?c=1&ob=mr&page=1').content
soup1=BeautifulSoup(html_text1,'lxml')

listings=soup1.find_all('a',class_='card card--clickable')

data = []

for listing in listings:
    price=listing.find('p', class_='card__price').text.split()[0]
    price=price.split()[0]
    title=listing.find('h2').text
    property_type=listing.find('p',class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--property-type').text
    bedrooms=listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bedrooms').text
    bathrooms=listing.find('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--bathrooms').text
    location=listing.find('p', class_='card__location').text
    
    data.append({
        'price':price,
        'title':title,
        'property_type':property_type,
        'bedrooms':bedrooms,
        'bathrooms':bathrooms,
        'location':location
    })

dataset=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

|  | price | title | property_type | bedrooms | bathrooms | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 35,000,000 | Fully Upgraded | Private Pool | Prime Location | Villa | 6 | District One Villas, District One, Mohammed Bin Rashid City, Dubai |
| 1 | 2,600,000 | Vacant | Brand New and Ready | Community View | Villa | 3 | La Quinta, Villanova, Dubai Land, Dubai |
| 2 | 8,950,000 | Exclusive | Newly Renovated | Prime Location | Villa | 4 | Jumeirah 3 Villas, Jumeirah 3, Jumeirah, Dubai |
| 3 | 3,500,000 | Brand New | Single Row | Vastu Compliant | Villa | 3 | Azalea, Arabian Ranches 2, Dubai |
| 4 | 1,455,000 | Limited Units | 3 Yrs Payment Plan | La Violeta TH | Townhouse | 3 | La Violeta 1, Villanova, Dubai Land, Dubai |